# SQL SELECTING * then select values from columns that end with

Tags: sql, join, sql-like

I have a following code;

```
Select * from test left join testtwo on test.testid = testtwo.id
```

I then need to select values from another column that is called 'code' from 'testtwo' and the values end with '100' ('%100')

I tried the following code but it didn't work:

```
Select * from test left join testtwo on test.testid = testtwo.id
union
SELECT * FROM testtwo
WHERE code LIKE '100%';

id    testid   code
1     1       0001100
2     2       0002100
3     3       0003100
4     4       0004100
```

Comment: update your question add that the related  tables schema a proper data sample  and the expected  result

Comment: If you want it to end in `100` use `LIKE '%100'`.

Comment: You are not clear. "select values from another column" does not describe what you want, and you give code that doesn't work. So we don't know what you want. Please give a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for a string column where the values end  with `100` you should use

```
 WHERE code LIKE '%100';
```

Looking to your sample  you could use

```
Select * 
from test 
INNER  join testtwo on test.testid = testtwo.id
WHERE code LIKE '%100';
```

If you want also '%400' you could use an OR condition

```
Select * 
from test 
INNER  join testtwo on test.testid = testtwo.id
WHERE code LIKE '%100' 
OR code LIKE '%400' ;
```

or use a union

```
Select * 
from test 
INNER  join testtwo on test.testid = testtwo.id
WHERE code LIKE '%100' 
union 
Select * 
from test 
INNER  join testtwo on test.testid = testtwo.id
WHERE code LIKE '%400'
```